# String concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

Is there a way to concatenate strings and variable values and new lines, in javascript?

My code:

```
var variab = "Make:"+ make \n 
        "Model:" + model  \n 
        "Date taken: " + dateTime  \n 
        "File name:" + fileName ;
variab = variab.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        document.getElementById('exifid').innerHTML = variab;});
```

make, model, dateTime and fileName are all variables that return specific values, and I want them to be displayed into a list-like form in my div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
var variab = "Make:" + make + "\n" +
    "Model:" + model + "\n" +
    "Date taken: " + dateTime + "\n" +
    "File name:" + fileName ;

variab = variab.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
document.getElementById('exifid').innerHTML = variab;
```

You can also put each line in an Array and use `.join("<br>")` to save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 1):

Why use the replace?

```
var variab = "Make:"+ make + "<br>" +
"Model:" + model  + "<br>" +
"Date taken: " + dateTime  + "<br>" +
"File name:" + fileName ;
document.getElementById('exifid').innerHTML = variab;
```

Comment: thanks! i didn't know I could do that, I've just started playing around with js. :)

Answer (score 1):

For greater readability, I'd do this:

```
var variab = [
    "Make:" + make,
    "Model:" + model, 
    "Date taken: " + dateTime,
    "File name:" + fileName
].join("<br />");
```

You're also free to include newlines within your fields this way.

Unless your needs grow more complex. In that case, I'd use a templating framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could stuff each element into an array and then join them.

```
var array = [
    "Make:"+ make,
    "Model:" + model,
    "Date taken: " + dateTime,
    "File name:" + fileName
];
document.getElementById('exifid').innerHTML = array.join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much, much better to abstract the data into a readable form using a JavaScript object, like below, if possible.

```
var variab = {
    "Make": "Audi",
    "Model": "A3",
    "Date Taken": 2006,
    "File Name": "audia3.doc"
}

var string = "";

for (var detail_type in variab){
    var detail_data = variab[detail_type];
    string += detail_type + ": " + detail_data + "<br/>"
}

document.getElementById('exifid').innerHTML = variab;
```